# SQL Server test container docker image appears to start but fails with deadlock during setup

Tags: sql-server, spring-boot, docker, testcontainers

I am using test containers to deploy a SQL Server locally for dev, its created using following:

```
new MSSQLServerContainer(DockerImageName
            .parse(sqlImageName)
            .asCompatibleSubstituteFor("mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server"))
            .acceptLicense()
    mssqlServerContainer.withPassword.....
    mssqlServerContainer.withReuse(false)
    mssqlServerContainer.withTmpFs(Collections.singletonMap("/testtmpfs", "rw"))
    mssqlServerContainer.start()
```

It USUALLY works fine, however on occasion it will crash and I have obtained the following log. I have googled the various errors and usually its a persistant error such as bad password which does not meet requirements or issue with certificate. This is not my issue as the crash is transient, it might happen once in a test suite or it might not happen for several runs.

I would appreciate any guidance as the relevant error I see is " Transaction (Process ID 20) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process" however this is happening during startup, if there was a deadlock during a test I could fix that, but this deadlock looks to happen before SQL even completes start up which is really confusing me...

```
2023-08-30 23:18:06.485 ERROR 4702 --- [    Test worker] t.s.d.i.com/mssql/server:2017-latest     : Log output from the failed container: SQL Server 2019 will run as non-root by default. This container is running as user root. To learn more visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2099216. 2023-08-30 23:14:11.55 Server      Setup step is copying system data file 'C:\templatedata\master.mdf' to '/var/opt/mssql/data/master.mdf'.

2023-08-30 23:14:11.61 Server      Did not find an existing master data file /var/opt/mssql/data/master.mdf, copying the missing default master and other system database files. If you have moved the database location, but not moved the database files, startup may fail. To repair: shutdown SQL Server, move the master database to configured location, and restart.

2023-08-30 23:14:11.62 Server      Setup step is copying system data file 'C:\templatedata\mastlog.ldf' to '/var/opt/mssql/data/mastlog.ldf'.

2023-08-30 23:14:11.63 Server      Setup step is copying system data file 'C:\templatedata\model.mdf' to '/var/opt/mssql/data/model.mdf'.

2023-08-30 23:14:11.65 Server      Setup step is copying system data file 'C:\templatedata\modellog.ldf' to '/var/opt/mssql/data/modellog.ldf'.

2023-08-30 23:14:11.68 Server      Setup step is copying system data file 'C:\templatedata\msdbdata.mdf' to '/var/opt/mssql/data/msdbdata.mdf'.

2023-08-30 23:14:11.70 Server      Setup step is copying system data file 'C:\templatedata\msdblog.ldf' to '/var/opt/mssql/data/msdblog.ldf'.

2023-08-30 23:14:11.78 Server      Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-CU29) (KB5010786) - 14.0.3436.1 (X64) 

    Mar 18 2022 13:21:03 

    Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation

    Developer Edition (64-bit) on Linux (Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS)

2023-08-30 23:14:11.79 Server      UTC adjustment: 0:00

2023-08-30 23:14:11.80 Server      (c) Microsoft Corporation.

2023-08-30 23:14:11.80 Server      All rights reserved.

2023-08-30 23:14:11.81 Server      Server process ID is 376.

2023-08-30 23:14:11.81 Server      Logging SQL Server messages in file '/var/opt/mssql/log/errorlog'.

2023-08-30 23:14:11.82 Server      Registry startup parameters: 

     -d /var/opt/mssql/data/master.mdf

     -l /var/opt/mssql/data/mastlog.ldf

     -e /var/opt/mssql/log/errorlog

2023-08-30 23:14:11.84 Server      SQL Server detected 1 sockets with 8 cores per socket and 8 logical processors per socket, 8 total logical processors; using 8 logical processors based on SQL Server licensing. This is an informational message; no user action is required.

2023-08-30 23:14:11.86 Server      SQL Server is starting at normal priority base (=7). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.

2023-08-30 23:14:11.87 Server      Detected 51539 MB of RAM. This is an informational message; no user action is required.

2023-08-30 23:14:11.87 Server      Using conventional memory in the memory manager.

2023-08-30 23:14:11.88 Server      Large Page Allocated: 32MB 

2023-08-30 23:14:11.88 Server      Page exclusion bitmap is enabled.

2023-08-30 23:14:12.22 Server      Buffer pool extension is already disabled. No action is necessary. 

2023-08-30 23:14:12.44 Server      InitializeExternalUserGroupSid failed. Implied authentication will be disabled.

2023-08-30 23:14:12.45 Server      Implied authentication manager initialization failed. Implied authentication will be disabled.

2023-08-30 23:14:12.46 Server      Successfully initialized the TLS configuration. Allowed TLS protocol versions are ['1.0 1.1 1.2']. Allowed TLS ciphers are ['ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA:AES128-SHA:!DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:!DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:!DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:!DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA'].

2023-08-30 23:14:12.53 Server      Query Store settings initialized with enabled = 1, 

2023-08-30 23:14:12.57 Server      The maximum number of dedicated administrator connections for this instance is '1'

2023-08-30 23:14:12.57 Server      Node configuration: node 0: CPU mask: 0x00000000000000ff:0 Active CPU mask: 0x00000000000000ff:0. This message provides a description of the NUMA configuration for this computer. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.

2023-08-30 23:14:12.65 Server      Using dynamic lock allocation.  Initial allocation of 2500 Lock blocks and 5000 Lock Owner blocks per node.  This is an informational message only.  No user action is required.

2023-08-30 23:14:12.69 Server      In-Memory OLTP initialized on standard machine.

2023-08-30 23:14:12.75 Server      Database Instant File Initialization: enabled. For security and performance considerations see the topic 'Database Instant File Initialization' in SQL Server Books Online. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.

ForceFlush is enabled for this instance. 

2023-08-30 23:14:12.79 Server      Software Usage Metrics is disabled.

2023-08-30 23:14:12.82 spid4s      Starting up database 'master'.

ForceFlush feature is enabled for log durability.

2023-08-30 23:14:12.94 spid4s      The tail of the log for database master is being rewritten to match the new sector size of 4096 bytes.  3072 bytes at offset 418816 in file /var/opt/mssql/data/mastlog.ldf will be written.

2023-08-30 23:14:13.29 spid4s      Converting database 'master' from version 862 to the current version 869.

2023-08-30 23:14:13.29 spid4s      Database 'master' running the upgrade step from version 862 to version 863.

2023-08-30 23:14:13.40 spid4s      Database 'master' running the upgrade step from version 863 to version 864.

2023-08-30 23:14:13.58 spid4s      Database 'master' running the upgrade step from version 864 to version 865.

2023-08-30 23:14:13.63 spid4s      Database 'master' running the upgrade step from version 865 to version 866.

2023-08-30 23:14:13.74 spid4s      Database 'master' running the upgrade step from version 866 to version 867.

2023-08-30 23:14:13.78 spid4s      Database 'master' running the upgrade step from version 867 to version 868.

2023-08-30 23:14:13.82 spid4s      Database 'master' running the upgrade step from version 868 to version 869.

2023-08-30 23:14:14.25 spid4s      Resource governor reconfiguration succeeded.

2023-08-30 23:14:14.25 spid4s      SQL Server Audit is starting the audits. This is an informational message. No user action is required.

2023-08-30 23:14:14.26 spid4s      SQL Server Audit has started the audits. This is an informational message. No user action is required.

2023-08-30 23:14:14.34 spid4s      SQL Trace ID 1 was started by login "sa".

2023-08-30 23:14:14.37 spid4s      Server name is '2fb783148168'. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.

2023-08-30 23:14:14.40 spid21s     Always On: The availability replica manager is starting. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.

2023-08-30 23:14:14.41 spid19s     Password policy update was successful.

2023-08-30 23:14:14.44 spid11s     Starting up database 'mssqlsystemresource'.

2023-08-30 23:14:14.45 spid21s     Always On: The availability replica manager is waiting for the instance of SQL Server to allow client connections. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.

2023-08-30 23:14:14.47 spid4s      Starting up database 'msdb'.

2023-08-30 23:14:14.47 spid11s     The resource database build version is 14.00.3436. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.

2023-08-30 23:14:14.56 spid11s     Starting up database 'model'.

2023-08-30 23:14:14.66 spid4s      The tail of the log for database msdb is being rewritten to match the new sector size of 4096 bytes.  512 bytes at offset 306688 in file /var/opt/mssql/data/MSDBLog.ldf will be written.

2023-08-30 23:14:14.66 spid19s     A self-generated certificate was successfully loaded for encryption.

2023-08-30 23:14:14.67 spid11s     The tail of the log for database model is being rewritten to match the new sector size of 4096 bytes.  2048 bytes at offset 75776 in file /var/opt/mssql/data/modellog.ldf will be written.

2023-08-30 23:14:14.69 spid19s     Server is listening on [ 'any' <ipv6> 1433].

2023-08-30 23:14:14.69 spid19s     Server is listening on [ 'any' <ipv4> 1433].

2023-08-30 23:14:14.71 Server      Server is listening on [ ::1 <ipv6> 1434].

2023-08-30 23:14:14.72 Server      Server is listening on [ 127.0.0.1 <ipv4> 1434].

2023-08-30 23:14:14.72 Server      Dedicated admin connection support was established for listening locally on port 1434.

2023-08-30 23:14:14.74 spid19s     SQL Server is now ready for client connections. This is an informational message; no user action is required.

2023-08-30 23:14:14.78 spid11s     Converting database 'model' from version 862 to the current version 869.

2023-08-30 23:14:14.79 spid11s     Database 'model' running the upgrade step from version 862 to version 863.

2023-08-30 23:14:14.80 spid4s      Converting database 'msdb' from version 862 to the current version 869.

2023-08-30 23:14:14.81 spid4s      Database 'msdb' running the upgrade step from version 862 to version 863.

2023-08-30 23:14:14.92 spid11s     Database 'model' running the upgrade step from version 863 to version 864.

2023-08-30 23:14:14.99 spid4s      Database 'msdb' running the upgrade step from version 863 to version 864.

2023-08-30 23:14:15.00 spid11s     Database 'model' running the upgrade step from version 864 to version 865.

2023-08-30 23:14:15.05 spid11s     Database 'model' running the upgrade step from version 865 to version 866.

2023-08-30 23:14:15.08 spid11s     Database 'model' running the upgrade step from version 866 to version 867.

2023-08-30 23:14:15.14 spid4s      Database 'msdb' running the upgrade step from version 864 to version 865.

2023-08-30 23:14:15.15 spid11s     Database 'model' running the upgrade step from version 867 to version 868.

2023-08-30 23:14:15.18 spid4s      Database 'msdb' running the upgrade step from version 865 to version 866.

2023-08-30 23:14:15.21 spid4s      Database 'msdb' running the upgrade step from version 866 to version 867.

2023-08-30 23:14:15.25 spid11s     Database 'model' running the upgrade step from version 868 to version 869.

2023-08-30 23:14:15.25 spid4s      Database 'msdb' running the upgrade step from version 867 to version 868.

2023-08-30 23:14:15.30 spid4s      Database 'msdb' running the upgrade step from version 868 to version 869.

2023-08-30 23:14:15.45 spid11s     Polybase feature disabled.

2023-08-30 23:14:15.46 spid11s     Clearing tempdb database.

2023-08-30 23:14:15.70 spid11s     Starting up database 'tempdb'.

2023-08-30 23:14:15.79 spid11s     The tempdb database has 1 data file(s).

2023-08-30 23:14:15.81 spid21s     The Service Broker endpoint is in disabled or stopped state.

2023-08-30 23:14:15.81 spid21s     The Database Mirroring endpoint is in disabled or stopped state.

2023-08-30 23:14:15.90 spid21s     Service Broker manager has started.

2023-08-30 23:14:16.00 spid4s      Recovery is complete. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.

2023-08-30 23:14:17.80 spid20s     Error: 1205, Severity: 13, State:
55.

2023-08-30 23:14:17.80 spid20s     Transaction (Process ID 20) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.

2023-08-30 23:14:17.81 spid20s     The default language (LCID 0) failed to be set for engine and full-text services.

2023-08-30 23:14:17.81 spid20s     An error occurred during server setup. See previous errors for more information.

2023-08-30 23:14:17.82 spid20s     SQL Trace was stopped due to server shutdown. Trace ID = '1'. This is an informational message only; no user action is required.

2023-08-30 23:18:06.663 ERROR 4702 --- [    Test worker] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
```

Comment: Why do you have template data for a master database from an older version? It's hard to troubleshoot the deadlock from a single line in an error file but it _looks_ like it had the problem while trying to enable full-text search. Could you try changing the config so that it doesn't enable that feature, and uses a master database from an instance running the right version and _without_ full-text installed? Or if you really need it see [this](https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-docker/issues/161)

Comment: (You should restore that master database on an instance running on the right version, and then use _those_ for your template. I can assure you that running those upgrade steps can't possibly make your deployment process smoother.)

Comment: I notice the image is server:2017-latest which pulls the image from docker, which is confusing because in the log it says 2019... I will swap this for server:2019-latest and see if it runs any differently